# How to set Autoscroll on and off in Textview in android application such as book application.?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I want to develop A Book application in which we can scroll page automatically.
I used Toggle button For On/of the scroll.
how can i start and stop the Text view to Scrolling automatically..?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried that, but you could start by looking at [Scroller](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html). You can start the scroller going any time with startScroll(), and set the end position to some really far distance.

The scroller just manages the offset accumulation over time, you still need to apply the values to the view manually. You can get offset values with getCurrX() / getCurrY().

Also see [scroll gesture](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll.html).

Not sure if this will help you but maybe somewhere to start anyway.